# Can't open excelfile after saving using filesaver

Tags: c#, excel, angular, angular-httpclient

In the backend I generate an Excel file and save this on a server. This goes well. But users must have the opportunity to save the excel sheet on their local computer. That's why I use FileSaver in the frontend.

When frontend gets the byte array, it saves a file. But when I open this file in Excel, I get the message that format/extension is not valid. What am I doing wrong?

backend:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetExcelAsync(){
        // do something in service layer
        var result = File.ReadAllBytes(excelFile);
        return Ok(result);
}
```

FrontEnd:

service.ts

```
public getExcelSheet(): Observable<any>{
        let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
        responseType:  'blob' as 'json'};
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url, options);
}
```

component.ts

```
public getSheet(){
        this.service.getExcelSheet().subscribe( response =>{
        const blob = new Blob([response], 
            {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'result.xlsx');})
}
```

Comment: sorry, I see what I'm  doing  wrong. It was the backend. I had to return a FileStreamResult. In the frontend the type of Blob has to be 'application/octetstream'

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you find the solution but I will add my two words here cause they may help.

When handling Blobs in Angular you can simplify everything by removing the generic getter like this:

```
public getExcelSheet() {
        return this.httpClient.get(this.url, { responseType:  'blob' });
}
```

Now, Angular knows and returns an `Observable<blob>`.